# how to merge two JSONArray with addAll

Tags: json, scala

everyone, I use this piece of code in java to merge two org.json.simple.JSONArray and it works perfectly:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

public class MergeJsonArrays {

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.add("one");
    jsonArray.add("two");
    jsonArray.add("three");

    JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray2.add("three");
    jsonArray2.add("four");

    jsonArray.addAll(jsonArray2);
    System.out.println(jsonArray);
  }

}
```

I want to transpose this code in scala so It look like this:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray

/**
  * Created by Administrator on 03/01/2018.
  */
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var jsonArray = new JSONArray
    jsonArray.add("one");
    jsonArray.add("two")
    jsonArray.add("three")

    var jsonArray2 = new JSONArray()
    jsonArray2.add("three")
    jsonArray2.add("four")

    jsonArray.addAll(jsonArray2)
  }
}
```

I get an error at lines with add:

> Error:(13, 15) overloaded method value add with alternatives:   (x$1:
>   E)Boolean    (x$1: java.util._1)Boolean    (x$1: (some
>   other)java.util._1)Boolean  cannot be applied to (String)
>       jsonArray.add("three")

and line with addAll:

> Error:(19, 15) overloaded method value addAll with alternatives:
>         (x$1: java.util.Collection[_ <: E])Boolean 
>         (x$1: java.util.Collection[_ <: java.util.*1])Boolean 
>         (x$1: java.util.Collection[* <: (some other)java.util._1])Boolean
>        cannot be applied to (org.json.simple.JSONArray)
>           jsonArray.addAll(jsonArray2)

do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [this library](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple), my first advice would be to stop doing it. It is quite old and probably predates Java generics. It was not updated for years. There are many modern and supported [Java](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) [libraries](https://github.com/google/gson) as well as [libraries](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) [written](https://github.com/playframework/play-json) in [Scala](https://github.com/circe/circe). Take a look and pick one.

If for some mysterious reasons you have to use that ancient library in Scala, you will need some hacks. The thing is that Scala is designed to be more type safe than Java and thus it doesn't work well when generic type is not specified at all. And this is exactly what happens with [`JSONArray`](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONArray.java#L19)

```
public class JSONArray extends ArrayList implements JSONAware, JSONStreamAware {
```

See how it is just `ArrayList` instead of `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Object>` or something like that. The only way to work this around in Scala that I know is to perform explicit cast like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val jsonArray1 = new JSONArray()
  val javaArrayList1: ArrayList[Any] = jsonArray1.asInstanceOf[ArrayList[Any]]
  javaArrayList1.add("one")
  javaArrayList1.add("two")
  javaArrayList1.add("three")

  val jsonArray2 = new JSONArray()
  val javaArrayList2: ArrayList[Any] = jsonArray2.asInstanceOf[ArrayList[Any]]
  javaArrayList2.add("three")
  javaArrayList2.add("four")

  javaArrayList1.addAll(javaArrayList2)
  // and then use JSON-specifc methods via jsonArray1 
}
```